# Project asset scheduling

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create an project asset scheduler in excel but am coming across an issue. I would like to see what project an asset will be used on given the asset number and calendar date.  For example, working from the list:

Asset  Project  Date
  1''''''''''''''''A''''''''      Jan1
  2'''''''''''''''       B     '''''' Jan3
  1   '''''''''''''    C    ''''''  Jan5

I would expect to see something like this
   ''''Jan1  Jan3  Jan5
1 ''  A   ''''''''''''''''''''         C
2     '''''''''''''''    B

I am using a the following formula: =IF((IF(VLOOKUP(asset,range,1)=asset,VLOOKUP(asset,range,3),""))=date,VLOOKUP(date,range,2),"") but it wont show me the project past the first date the asset is scheduled.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it's quite hard to make out. Please edit the question to include detailed descriptions of what you've got, what you've tried, how it's worked out and crucially, what exact result you're trying to achieve. See the help center for info on how to add images to posts; as you're new they'll show up as links for now but someone will be along shortly to convert to images directly in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

I've tried to recreate your schedule in Excel. Its often easier to use a screen cap to help keep the question clear.  Please see the details below. Hopefully, it will help answer your question.

[image]

Best Regards,
Brad